# Different result of the program than was expected, maybe because of index of arrays

Tags: pascal, freepascal

i have to do the following thing.
Make a program in Pascal that after has read a text with a list of nums., it will return the numb. of the nums that appear less than one times in the text.

The text that will be read from the program should be like that.

In the first line there are two nums. seperated by a space, n and m. N is the number of nums that exist, like if the text contains the numbers 1,2,3,4, n is 4 (1..n). M is how many lines follow. Every line has a couple of nums, a,b, (1=b) a and b are separated by a space.

The file that the program will make will have written on it a num., that says how many nyms are appeared less than two tims in the text.

All the nums. are Integer.

0=

I have finished it, but the problem is that at the new text that p has to be written, p is always 1, For me the problem is at the place that i have the bold letters, it might be because i in count and i in a arrays are different, how can i correct this???
Thank you in advance.

```
program MyProgr;

var
  F: text;
  t:Textfile;
  a,count:array of Integer;
  b:Integer;
  i,int:Integer;
  countnums:Integer;
  n,m:String;
  lin,nums:Integer;
  Small,Big:Integer;

procedure DoWhatEver(S: string);
begin
  val(s,int);
  Write(s,'     ');
  for i:=Small to Big do
    if (a[i]=int) then
  count[i]:=count[i]+1;
end;

procedure FilltheArray;
begin
  for i:=Small to Big do
    a[i]:=i+1 ;
end;

procedure ProcessString;
var
  Strng, S: string;
  Last, P: integer;
begin
  readln(F,Strng);
  Last:=0;
  while Last<length(Strng) do
  begin
    P:=Last+1;
    while (P<=length(Strng)) and (Strng[P]<>' ') do
      inc(P);
    S:=copy(Strng,Last+1,(P-Last-1));
    DoWhatEver(S);
    Last:=P;
  end
end;

procedure ProcessStringA;
var
  Strng: string;
  Last, P: integer;
begin
  readln(F,Strng);
  Last:=0;
  while Last<length(Strng) do
  begin
    P:=Last+1;
    while (P<=length(Strng)) and (Strng[P]<>' ') do
      inc(P);
    n:=copy(Strng,Last+1,(P-Last-1));
    Val(n,nums);
    Last:=P;
  end
end;

procedure ProcessStringB;
var
  Strng: string;
  Last, P: integer;
begin
  readln(F,Strng);
  Last:=0;
  while Last<length(Strng) do
  begin
    P:=Last+1;
    while (P<=length(Strng)) and (Strng[P]<>' ') do
      inc(P);
    m:=copy(Strng,Last+1,(P-Last-1));
    Val(m,lin);
    Last:=P;
  end
end;

begin
  assign(F,'myfile.txt');
  reset(F);
  ProcessStringA;
  Writeln(nums);
  ProcessStringB;
  Writeln(lin);
  setlength(a,nums);
  Small:=Low(a);
  Big:=High(a);
  for i:= Small to big do
    count[i]:=0;
  FillTheArray;
  while not eof(F) do 
    ProcessString;

  for i:=Small to Big do
  begin
    if count[i]=2 then
      countnums:=countnums+1;
  end;
  Close(f);
  Assign(t,'fileout.txt');
  Rewrite(t);
  Writeln(t,countnums);
  close(t);
end.
```

Comment: Once again (I've asked before): Please work on properly formatting your code when posting here. You can preview it before posting to see how it will look. If you format it properly, it's easier to read and understand when we're trying to help you solve your problem. I've formatted it (again) to give you an example that might help. People get annoyed having to do the formatting for you every time. (Also, you have the same issue with unallocated memory that you do in your other post with this same code - another user reformatted that one for you as well.) Thanks.

Comment: (1) "return the numb. of the nums that appear less than one times in the text."; (2) "how many nyms are appeared less than two tims in the text."; (3) "if count[i]=2 then countnums:=countnums+1;". So do you need the numbers that appear (1) LESS THAN ONE TIME, or (2) LESS THAN TWO TIMES, or (3) EXACTLY TWO TIMES?